# a function that returns two lists, how do i save them separately?

Tags: python, list, function, plot, graph

Hello so i have this function that returns two lists, (list_y and list_t), i wanna use these lists separately, because i want to draw a graph using them (list_y represent the y label and list_t represents the x labels )

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt


def f(y):
    return float(alpha) * float(y) - float(beta) * (float(y) * float(y))


def runge_k(y, t, h):
    list_y = []
    list_t = [0]
    i = 0
    c = 0
    while i <= t:
        k1 = h * f(y)
        k2 = h * f(y + k1 / 2)
        k3 = h * f(y + k2 / 2)
        k4 = h * f(y + k3)
        y = y + (k1 + 2 * k2 + 2 * k3 + k4) / 6
        list_y.append(y)
        c = c + h
        list_t.append(c)
        i = i + 1
    return list_y, list_t


alpha = input("Enter the value of ⍺: ")
beta = input("Enter the value of β: ")
H = float(input("Enter the value of H: "))
Y = float(input("Enter the first value of Y:  "))
x = 100.0

l = runge_k(Y, 100, H)
print(l)
```

the output of the function is :

```
([0.011201112806750443, 0.012545631403805439, 0.014050458612363977, 0.01573443395285716, 0.017618541424573964, 0.019726135952966208, 0.022083189216059864, 0.024718555292191694, 0.02766425619403988, 0.030955786842025518, 0.03463243835243875, 0.038737637636111356, 0.04331930018143671, 0.04843019148617472, 0.054128290857940804, 0.06047714917489319, 0.06754622963983758, 0.07541121753448432, 0.08415428146282856, 0.09386426456580949, 0.10463677973443844, 0.11657417804190659, 0.12978535462914978, 0.14438535138454225, 0.16049471135230406, 0.1782385364284871, 0.1977451982650515, 0.2191446532773082, 0.24256631726502184, 0.26813646454117096, 0.29597513174998036, 0.3261925287402207, 0.35888498858245993, 0.3941305261065944, 0.431984118303173, 0.47247286849299686, 0.5155912658247555, 0.5612967974445097, 0.6095062063640646, 0.6600927066776591, 0.7128844625412082, 0.7676646028017651, 0.8241729766202839, 0.8821097580711978, 0.9411408854299051, 1.0009051842753536, 1.0610228869750673, 1.121105140744467, 1.1807640076976247, 1.2396224150914288, 1.297323518572715, 1.3535389950249694, 1.4079758771534912, 1.4603816664697027, 1.5105475990793786, 1.5583100736397517, 1.6035503692532367, 1.6461928731211544, 1.6862020984673047, 1.723578802144693, 1.758355511776453, 1.7905917500342743, 1.8203692056325882, 1.8477870536978014, 1.8729575783880543, 1.8960022026958443, 1.9170479874960626, 1.936224625954069, 1.9536619310795573, 1.9694877933422312, 1.9838265711311076, 1.9967978684081193, 2.0085156500351853, 2.0190876448264805, 2.028614988392021, 2.0371920614492827, 2.0449064838100743, 2.0518392291859135, 2.058064830925566, 2.0636516535514624, 2.0686622093405234, 2.073153503114562, 2.0771773918331746, 2.080780948521151, 2.084006822539428, 2.0868935902636845, 2.0894760919146513, 2.0917857516378744, 2.0938508790053763, 2.095696950951642, 2.0973468738013863, 2.0988212255318137, 2.100138478767843, 2.1013152052608537, 2.1023662627715907, 2.103304965383844, 2.104143238332177, 2.1048917584462252, 2.1055600813055704, 2.1061567561705723, 2.1066894297118397], [0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.30000000000000004, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.7999999999999999, 0.8999999999999999, 0.9999999999999999, 1.0999999999999999, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4000000000000001, 1.5000000000000002, 1.6000000000000003, 1.7000000000000004, 1.8000000000000005, 1.9000000000000006, 2.0000000000000004, 2.1000000000000005, 2.2000000000000006, 2.3000000000000007, 2.400000000000001, 2.500000000000001, 2.600000000000001, 2.700000000000001, 2.800000000000001, 2.9000000000000012, 3.0000000000000013, 3.1000000000000014, 3.2000000000000015, 3.3000000000000016, 3.4000000000000017, 3.5000000000000018, 3.600000000000002, 3.700000000000002, 3.800000000000002, 3.900000000000002, 4.000000000000002, 4.100000000000001, 4.200000000000001, 4.300000000000001, 4.4, 4.5, 4.6, 4.699999999999999, 4.799999999999999, 4.899999999999999, 4.999999999999998, 5.099999999999998, 5.1999999999999975, 5.299999999999997, 5.399999999999997, 5.4999999999999964, 5.599999999999996, 5.699999999999996, 5.799999999999995, 5.899999999999995, 5.999999999999995, 6.099999999999994, 6.199999999999994, 6.299999999999994, 6.399999999999993, 6.499999999999993, 6.5999999999999925, 6.699999999999992, 6.799999999999992, 6.8999999999999915, 6.999999999999991, 7.099999999999991, 7.19999999999999, 7.29999999999999, 7.39999999999999, 7.499999999999989, 7.599999999999989, 7.699999999999989, 7.799999999999988, 7.899999999999988, 7.999999999999988, 8.099999999999987, 8.199999999999987, 8.299999999999986, 8.399999999999986, 8.499999999999986, 8.599999999999985, 8.699999999999985, 8.799999999999985, 8.899999999999984, 8.999999999999984, 9.099999999999984, 9.199999999999983, 9.299999999999983, 9.399999999999983, 9.499999999999982, 9.599999999999982, 9.699999999999982, 9.799999999999981, 9.89999999999998, 9.99999999999998, 10.09999999999998])
```

Comment: Keep in mind that the actual output doesn't matter to the users reading your question, it should be easily readable

Comment: It doesn't return two lists. It returns a single tuple, which *contains* two lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or in function:

```
 a, b = runge_k(Y, 100, H)
```

instead of:

```
l = runge_k(Y, 100, H)
```

then when you will call 'a' you will get only one :)
if you want to get this as an output of function then

`print(l)` replace with `return a,b`